# Url is not showing in ngnix logs

Tags: nginx, logging

I deployed my application on nginx server and I am also using basic ngnix authentication.

I also customize my logs in ngnix

```
log_format timed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '$status "$request" $http_host';
```

but I need complete url in my logs, from $http_host it is showing IP like "11.110.11.11: only not my url eg. 11.110.11.11/dashboard

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of variables to get full url

```
log_format timed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '$status "$request" "$scheme://$http_host$request_uri"';
```